# testCompile for Gradle dependencies

Tags: database, spring-boot, gradle, h2

I need Gradle h2 dependency for H2 DB. In MVN repository I see only `testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.188'.` I read that testCompile is for testing and I dont need this dependency for testing, I just need dependency \for creating H2 DB in my Spring Boot app. Should I just use `testCompile` dependency for H2 or should be there regular compile dependency?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it would be to add the following regular compile dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
compile "com.h2database:h2"
```